# I think TM package cannot plot 2 letter word like bg or go or su

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to do text mining .. below is the code but surprising that TM cannot show 2 letter word like bg

see sample output of 2 variation

[[1]]
<>
 g hargrov hargrg phone inquir led complaint custom respons sts got alarm pump alarm ts per dop patient bg treat manual inject expl alarm possibl caus check alarm hx found cust way hospit call drop cust unhappi line state explain alarm explain alarm cust call disconnect sts car drive pump backseat continu troubleshoot cust say pump without battrey time custom outcom pertain complaint call disconect complet cust sts car drive way hospit sts go work go admitt call disconnect ship noth return noth

--- A three letter word is shown up

```
> dtm_list_harms<-DocumentTermMatrix(tdm[1],list(dictionary = c("led")))
> inspect(dtm_list_harms)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 1/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 3
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    Terms
Docs led
   1   1
```

-- but 2 letter word does not ..

```
> dtm_list_harms<-DocumentTermMatrix(tdm[1],list(dictionary = c("bg")))
> inspect(dtm_list_harms)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 0/1
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 2
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    Terms
Docs bg
   1  0
```

a bug in TM package or is there a technique i dont know?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (please make your examples reproducible with data from now on):

```
dtm_list_harms<-DocumentTermMatrix(tdm[1],list(dictionary = c("led"), ,control=list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf)))
```

This isn't perfect but this is because I didn't have much to work with.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, The solutions is correct just the syntax needs to be fixed little bit..     dtm_list_harms<-DocumentTermMatrix(tdm[1],list(dictionary = c("led"),wordLengths=c(1,Inf))